# Android crash when delete record

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

in a table SQLite. I have a list of strings that I see is in a listview by button I delete each record.

But if for example in the written record and the word "caffè" everything works fine, but if it is written the word " caffe' "the app crashes why?
thanks

```
String nome = tv.getText().toString();
            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(NomeTable.TABLE_NAME, NomeTable.NOME_CAT + "='" + nome_cat + "'", null);
            db.close();
            finish();
```

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: can you try ``db.delete(NomeTable.TABLE_NAME, NomeTable.NOME_CAT + "=?", new String[]{nome_cat});`` ? Also.. are you sure nome_cat contains anything? it's quite a challenge to help you without a logcat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the ' is a special character in SQL.

So you end up with `='caffe''` which is invalid due to double ''.

You want to instead use the whereArgs param as well.

`db.delete(NomeTable.TABLE_NAME, NomeTable.NOME_CAT + "= ?", new String[]{nome_cat});`

That will escape your ' character for you and shouldn't mess you the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would think `nome_cat` contains some symbols not alowed by the SQL syntax. You might want to use [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) to build your query.